# Windows 8 will not load color profiles - why?

Tags: windows, windows-8, color-profiles

I have a Spyder3Express color calibration device. Under Windows 7 the utility that came with it would happily load the custom profile I created with it without any hassles.

Under Windows 8 (have just upgraded) there is no visible color shift when it says it has loaded the profile.

I have gone into the Windows color management settings and when I select any profile and hit 'Set as Default' nothing happens. They all look the same.

So Windows doesn't throw an error, but none of the profiles cause any color shifts at all.

I have tried a large number of things, such as changing the global color settings for all user accounts and installing other color management software to see if it will load the profiles.

The only way I can get a color shift is if I create a profile using Windows built in utility. Profiles created this way change the appearance of the screen, but any downloaded or created profiles make no difference.

I am out of ideas. Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

This may be similar to a problem I ran into after upgrading to Windows 8.1 RTM: none of my display color profiles were working any more.

In my case the upgrade had turned off the system-wide "Use Windows display calibration" setting. [Turning that setting back on fixed it.](https://superuser.com/a/643434/207268)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

No idea why, but after I reinstalled the Datacolor software for the 4th time Windows color management started behaving again and everything is working fine.

Good news - but no idea what changed so this answer won't be helpful to anyone else :(

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has the "Intel HD graphics" icon on the taskbar, try running that to create the desired settings.